# Why does Windows spooler require an administrator account?

Tags: windows-xp, printing, print-spooler

Does anyone know what changes I might need to make to allow restricted users to print using a printer configured for spooling?

My Windows XP SP3 system currently requires me to use an Admin account for printing if the printer is configured to spool documents before printing.  If the printer is configured for direct printing it works for all accounts.  This used to work and some months back it just stopped, and I can't pin down why.

The printer, which is an HP PSC 1200 (an old printer) itself is configured for Everyone to have Print authority and my specific (restricted) account to have Full authority, that is Print, Manage Printers and Manager Documents.

My HDD is locked down for restricted users given them only read authority to the entire file system except their data directories, which is how I have run my systems for years.

I assume there may be a directory somewhere that I need to allow users to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the spool folder itself (but apparently not it's contents).

To fix this:

1. Using Explorer, navigate to My Computer, Control Panel, Printers & Faxes.
2. Select File Menu, then Server Properties, and select the Advanced tab.
3. Relocate the Spool Folder to be within some folder for which the USERS principle can list the contents.  For example "C:\Temp\zSpool".
4. Ensure that the spool folder itself does not grant USERS permissions and that permissions are not inherited, to prevent users from directly messing with it's contents.

Then print a test document using a restricted account to ensure all is as it should be.

Note 1: Everything in my experience tells me this answer is crap, since the printing should be done by the SYSTEM account which has full access to everything involved.  Further, the USERS principle actually has less access to the new location and spooler directory.  But it absolutely works.

Note 2: For probably completely unrelated reasons, within minutes of getting my (not so smart) HP Printer to print again it decided it's top cover was open even though it was not and I subsequently had to configure the printer to uncheck the "Enable advanced printing features" option.  <Sarcasm>Apparently, one of the advanced features is to be very confused about the state of the printer</Sarcasm>.